# How to set textwidth to spverb globally

Tags: verbatim

I'm using `\spverb` to show inline code but if there is a long code it doesn't wraping up properly since it only breaks at spaces.

But if I use `\parabox` with `\textlength` it works just fine. Is there a way to config spverb globally to use this size?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document} 

\spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|

\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
\spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|
}
\end{document}
```

#### Intended output is second one

[image]

Comment: Erh, your example does not compile. Please don't ignore compilation errors.

Comment: I would never expect anything verbatim-like to be usable inside the argument to a macro. Use the env version instead: `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}`.

Comment: Hey it's working fine. I'm using overleaf.

Comment: If you are using texlive.net just remove `\parabox` example and it work's fine. Give me an example how to use an env correctly with size.

Comment: With `\parbox` it is not workign fine, neither locally or in overleaf. As I said don't ignore compilation errors. Overleaf reports 3 compilation errors (though there is just one, the fact that you cannot use anything verbatim like inside the argument to a macro, unless it is very specially made, and `\parbox` is not).

Comment: Then how to specify a fixed width for verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code don't work (you obtain errors in the log), you could not have a `\verb` (or similar) in a `\parbox`, as explained by daleif.

With `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}` you obtain indeed (see the second block):

[image]

I don't know why in a minipage environment, the verbatim text is raggedright, however.

For the inline `\spverb|...|`, the problem is that in monospaced fonts, the width of space characters are fixed.

But, there are some workarounds (see below; perhaps there exists betters; note that halas, with the Latin Modern Mono Proportional font, quotes are curly, I don't know how to made it straight).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{document} 

\blindtext

% As the paragraph is justified, there is space for the beginning of the word "any",
% but no hyphenation available in verbatim, and spaces have fixed width.
% So you obtain Overfull \hbox
\spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|

% Here, there is spaces with variable width for the first line, so, the first line 
% is correctly justified. No variable spaces available for the next lines,
% so you obtain Overfull \hbox for the next lines
If you have some words at the begin: \spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|. It's better on lines with some available rubber lengths (here only the first line).

% With the package fvextra, you could ask for breaklines, but as in the first example,
% there is no variable space available, and you ask for a justified text
\Verb[breaklines]{println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");}

% Here, you allow the line breaking anywhere, so it's OK. Note the (customizable)
% symbol at the end of lines. You can also add a customizable symbol a the begin
% of the line after the break
\Verb[breaklines, breakanywhere]{println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");}

% Here, in a raggedright paragraph, there is no problem. If the word doesn't fit
% in the current line, it goes in the next line.
% the output is like the minipage environment (but you are still in a inline verbatim)
\begin{flushleft}
\Verb[breaklines]{println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");}   
\end{flushleft}

% Here we change the tt font to a proportional (but looks like the former tt)
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt} % uses Latin Modern Mono proportional

% Generally, no problem if you uses proportional fonts (the spaces have variable width)
\spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|

\Verb[breaklines]{println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");}

% But on some complicated situations, it goes wrong (I replaced "and outputs"
% by "andouputs".) The first line is OK, but not the second.
\spverb|println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input andoutputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");println!("A "Hello, World!" program is generally a computer program that ignores any input and outputs or displays a message similar to "Hello, World!".");|

\end{document}
```

[image]